# Karate fails to close earlier started Crome processes

Tags: webdriver, karate

In my project I use Karate 0.9.5, Oracle JDK8.
From time to time in our pipeline I see a problem. Karate fails to close earlier started Crome processes. Is there any solution to this problem?
I try to solved by explicitly call close() and quit() it didn't help. After running process was finished I found a couple of active chrome process on the server.
Here's a log:

```
12:51:45.227 preferred port 9222 not available, will use: 52436
12:51:47.524 request:
1 > GET http://localhost:52436/json
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Host: localhost:52436
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.11 (Java/1.8.0_181)

12:51:47.584 response time in milliseconds: 58,31
1 < 200
1 < Content-Length: 361
1 < Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
[ {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:52436/devtools/page/4BD6A5C19E01B01D88995CD69367F81F",
   "id": "4BD6A5C19E01B01D88995CD69367F81F",
   "title": "",
   "type": "page",
   "url": "about:blank",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:52436/devtools/page/4BD6A5C19E01B01D88995CD69367F81F"
} ]


12:51:47.584 root frame id: 4BD6A5C19E01B01D88995CD69367F81F
12:51:47.632 >> {"method":"Target.activateTarget","params":{"targetId":"4BD6A5C19E01B01D88995CD69367F81F"},"id":1}
12:51:47.638 << {"id":1,"result":{}}
12:51:47.639 >> {"method":"Page.enable","id":2}
12:51:47.883 << {"id":2,"result":{}}
12:51:47.885 >> {"method":"Runtime.enable","id":3}
12:51:47.889 << {"method":"Runtime.executionContextCreated","params":{"context":{"id":1,"origin":"://","name":"","auxData":{"isDefault":true,"type":"default","frameId":"4BD6A5C19E01B01D88995CD69367F81F"}}}}
12:51:47.890 << {"id":3,"result":{}}
12:51:47.890 >> {"method":"Target.setAutoAttach","params":{"autoAttach":true,"waitForDebuggerOnStart":false,"flatten":true},"id":4}
12:51:47.892 << {"id":4,"result":{}}
12:52:02.894 << timed out after milliseconds: 15000 - [id: 4, method: Target.setAutoAttach, params: {autoAttach=true, waitForDebuggerOnStart=false, flatten=true}]
12:52:02.917 driver config / start failed: failed to get reply for: [id: 4, method: Target.setAutoAttach, params: {autoAttach=true, waitForDebuggerOnStart=false, flatten=true}], options: {type=chrome, showDriverLog=true, httpConfig={readTimeout=60000}, headless=true, target=null}
```

I think the easiest way to solve it is to extend root web driver interface com.intuit.karate.driver.Driver by adding additional method like getPID(). This method must return PID of launched process.

Answer (score 0):

Can you log a bug and also provide some information as to what happened before this, are you using the Docker image etc. It looks like the previous `Scenario` did not shut down clearly.

But before that do you mind upgrading to 0.9.6.RC3 (just released) and trying that ? There have been a couple of tweaks to the life-cycle especially trying to close Chrome without waiting for a response. Also it may be worth adding a couple of changes a) `Target.setAutoAttach` without waiting and b) add configure option to not start Chrome if the port is in use

Comment: Hi Peter. Yes I definitely try 0.9.6.RC3 first. If it doesn't help I will provide you all the necessary information.

Comment: @Rassoll that's great to know, thanks for confirming